# Receiving an error on my JS for local storage. Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set properties of null (setting 'checked')

Tags: javascript, onclick, local-storage, onload

For my javascript I am receiving an error when server = true and then creating a page refresh. It makes me click my lightmode/darkmode button twice before it will change modes. I can not figure out why it can't read checked (occuring at this line in my JS under the stored() function: `document.getElementById("ID_HERE").checked = true;`)

**Error:**
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set properties of null (setting 'checked')

**HTML:**

```
<body onload="stored(); toggle()">
<label for="ID_HERE" class="toggle-switchy" >
    <input checked type="checkbox" name="server" id="ID_HERE">
        <span class="toggle" onclick="toggle(); stored()" id="saveDarkLight"></span>
      <span class="switch"></span>
    </span>
</label>
```

**JS:**

```
function stored() {
    const storedValue = localStorage.getItem("server");
    if(storedValue === 'true'){
      lightmode()
      document.getElementById("ID_HERE").checked = true;
    }
    else{
       darkmode()
       document.getElementById("ID_HERE").checked = false;
    }
  }

function toggle() {
    if(document.getElementById("ID_HERE").checked) {
      lightmode()
      var input = document.getElementById("ID_HERE");
      localStorage.setItem("server", input.checked);
    }
    else {
        darkmode()
        var input = document.getElementById("ID_HERE");
        localStorage.setItem("server", input.checked);
    }
}

function darkmode() { 
  const bodyChanges = document.querySelectorAll('.margin_body');
  for (let i = 0; i < bodyChanges.length; i++) {
    bodyChanges[i].style.background = '#0c0a0f';
  }
}

function lightmode() { 
  const bodyChanges = document.querySelectorAll('.margin_body');
  for (let i = 0; i < bodyChanges.length; i++) {
    bodyChanges[i].style.background = 'white';
  }
}
```

Comment: The error in the question title is different from the one in the question body.

Comment: The error in the body means that `document.getElementById("ID_HERE")` can't find the element. We don't have enough information to tell you why this is. It would help if you could provide a [mcve].

Comment: Sorry, the one in the body is the one I need help with. It's been changed in the title

Comment: Without further insight, remove the `onload` attribute from the body tag, add the `defer` attribute to your `<script>` tag that loads that JavaScript, and finally at the tail of the JavaScript file place calls to `store(); toggle();`. My guess is you'll have better luck.

Comment: Although this did work in making it only one click, the local storage did not load.